# Is it possible to change the status bar text (foreground) color to an arbitrary color (i.e. not black or white)?

Tags: ios, colors, ios7, statusbar

Does anyone know how to change the status bar text color?

I want the *text* to be in the color orange.

I'm not talking about the regular black or white color

```
`UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`; or `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque`; or whatever.
```

Comment: Please guys, don't you think I already tried to find a solution on Google ?? However, as I mentioned, I'm looking for a way to change the TEXT color, and not the background color of the status bar.

Comment: IMHO, the title of the question should be changed to "Is it possible to change status bar **text** color **to orange**?" because that is what the OP wants to know. Therefore I think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Although this question is old, **I have voted to reopen this question.** The answers in the alleged duplicates answer the question of how you can change the status bar color to black or white. The OP explicitly states that he is not interested in black or white! One answer below even explicitly (and wrongly) states that "You can't change it to orange". This is not true. I've posted code that actually works and which can change the status bar text color to any color, even orange. The OP even explicitely states that he is not talking about black or white, so the other answers are no dupes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no **documented way** to change the *text* color to orange. However, it is definitively possible, because I just tried it out and it worked.

Disclaimer: this is all undocumented territorry... it will probably not be approved when you submit it to the app store. however, you may be lucky...

In iOS 7 you can do this:

```
/// sets the status bar text color. returns YES on success.
/// currently, this only
/// works in iOS 7. It uses undocumented, inofficial APIs.
BOOL setStatusBarColor(UIColor *color)
{
    id statusBarWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"];
    id statusBar = [statusBarWindow valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

    SEL setForegroundColor_sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"setForegroundColor:");
    if([statusBar respondsToSelector:setForegroundColor_sel]) {
        // iOS 7+
        [statusBar performSelector:setForegroundColor_sel withObject:color];
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

in iOS5 and iOS6 it may be possible too, but I haven't tried, because it is much more work. However I have found a method of interest (available in iOS 5 and iOS 6). Class `UIStatusBarItemView` has an instance method called `-textColorForStyle:` (which takes an integer and returns an object). You may be able to monkey-patch it to return any color you like.

Comment: All right, this is what I call an awesome answer !! However, I'll need my app to be published, cross the finger :) Btw, can I asked you how did you found out that 
 id statusBarWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"];
    id statusBar = [statusBarWindow valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

will return the correct objects?

Comment: 1.: once upon a time, I found an app called "Runtime Browser" on the web. (it's not [this one](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser), it may work well though, i just haven't tried it.) I made it ARC-ready, added features to show me the method signatures, read up on docs to understand the runtime system, so now I know that `@12@0:4i8` has the meaning of 'method that takes an integer and returns an object', improved performance, etc. this app shows me all the classes that there are in the system, and all method names and for each method the method signature.

Comment: 2.: i use the debugger extensively, set breakpoints into "debug-methods" that contain temporary variables, or does something experimentative, then I step through my methods and inspect the objects, their class-names, etc. When I found something, I test it in iOS 5, 6 and 7 to see where it works and where it breaks. you really need enough test devices, and you always should work on the device and not in the simulator. occasionally i test stuff also in the simulator, to make sure it doesn't crash there.

Comment: 3.: monkey patching helps often, if all else fails. but you have to be really careful when you are using it for anything except doing research. and its also more time-consuming, so I only do it if I really need to know something.

Comment: Is Apple rejecting app with this code? I want to give a try...

Comment: Well, IMHO there is a small chance that Apple will not reject this code. It should go okay with the static analyzer. I'm not sure wether it will go okay with the reviewer.

Comment: Hey mates, I don't know yet, my app isn't finished yet. I'll let you know guys if I changed the status bar text color for the release.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't change it to orange.**

**Black** and **white** are currently the only available status bar content / texr colors.

The Apple UI guidelines mentioned that **Don’t create a custom status bar**.

The default color of the content / text in the status bar is **black** and this can cause the status bar to become unreadable if the content behind the status bar is dark.

In order to remedy this issue you can set the `UIStatusBarStyle` of your application and/or views. `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` changes the color of the content in the status bar to white; alternately, `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` sets the color of the status bar content to black.

[image]

Comment: I'll mark yours as answer because this question is now a mess. But thank you ! You're right, black and white are the only available colors atm.

Comment: @user1147981: check out my new answer... orange is possible too