# How to log network performance data in iOS applications?

Tags: ios, performance, networking, logging

Apple's SDK agreement limits an applications' scope of data access, but has anyone found how to log any of the following information (even if it has been shut down by apple)?:

Operating System,
OS Version,
Network Name,
Technology,
Device,
Latitude,
Longitude,
Time,
RSSI,
RSRP,
RSRQ,
RSSNR,
Cell ID,
Ping Time,
Packet Loss,
Ping Success Rate,
Download Speed,
Upload Speed,
Call Event Type,

This can be accomplished fairly easily on Android, but I'm trying to find a way to collect this data on iOS where there are more roadblocks in the way. All feedback is greatly appreciated.

Even if you have been rejected by Apple but you've found how to get this info, how'd you do it? Ultimately I'd like to create an app that can log this data in a passive way (doesn't need to be open), but active logging would work too.

Comment: yes, i have. this are actually >10 different questions. Example: OS version: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`

Comment: You're right @Michael , it is a pretty complex question. Is there any chance you could elaborate here or perhaps even email me with more details on how you accomplished this? It would be extremely appreciated. You can email me at zacharycooner@gmail.com

Comment: i haven't done all of them. but OS is always iOS. network name: see CocoaAsyncSocket... device: see UIDevice, latitude/longitude/height: see "location programming guide". the others: i have no idea... cell-ID: don't know, you have to do reasearch [maybe hacking the statusbar would help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23387715/754705)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Latitude, Longitude, I think you can get using **locationManager** from **Core Location**. This provided that the user of the app allows you to get the location.

To know the network status, you may try **Reachability** sample code by Apple
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I don't think you can get as much information from iOS compare with Android as Apple really cares about the Privacy of it users.